# Query to return all documents in which a field matches any element from a list in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, falconframework

I have two MongoDB collections. One is `Users` and another is `Posts`. In the user collection, each document stores a list of usernames that that particular user follows. For example,

```
{
    'username' : 'username',
    'following' : ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
    ...
}
```

And, each document in the `Posts` collection consists of an `author` field. Now, in order to create a news feed, I want to show **only** the posts of the users that a particular user follows.

```
{
    'content' : 'some content',
    'author' : 'user1',
    ...
}
```

Can I write a query in MongoEngine (Python) such that the `Posts` collection is queried and it returns all the documents in which the `author` field is one of the authors from the `following` list? (The list of the people that user follows) in a chronological manner.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following model and data:

```
class User(Document):
    following = ListField(StringField())

class Post(Document):
    author = StringField()

User(following=['A', 'B']).save()
Post(author='B').save()
```

You need to have the list already (you can't query Post with a `user_id` directly), and then you can achieve what you want by using the `__in` operator:

```
user = User.objects.first()
print(user.following)    # [u'A', u'B']
Post.objects(author__in=user.following)    # [<Post: Post object>]
```